# What's a good program to practice buffer overflows on (for educational purposes only)?

Tags: security, ftp, buffer-overflow

I have recently learned the basics of buffer overflows, and I have written a few very simple pieces of C/C++ code with unsafe buffers and have produced some interesting results.

Now my question is this: Can you name a program that's actually out there in the wild that has a known buffer overflow vulnerability? I am especially looking for something that runs over a network, if possible.

I have seen tutorials and read articles and even watched videos that have talked about/demonstrated the buffer overflow vulnerability in the Ability FTP Server ver. 2.34, but I can not for the life of me find a single copy of it online anywhere. I can find plenty of downloads of non-vulnerable versions, but non of the educationally useful ones. Any help on this front would also be appreciated.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: What exactly do you want to see?

Comment: Well, I would ultimately like to see arbitrary code executed, preferably across a network on a separate machine (both my machines). I'm just interested in an example that's as close to a field test as I can get without actually hacking someone's machine.

Comment: As I mentioned above, I have done this. I would really like to test it on a full product that someone else wrote.

Comment: Yeah I doubt that's going to be easy to come across as I would hope people would prevent against that as it is a common type of attack. Is there a specific reason you want to see a full product fall prey to a buffer overflow? Wouldn't you get the same results out of just writing a program that would be vulnerable, I mean the same thing would happen.

Comment: I'm interested in learning about what exploits have actually been found and used in the past. It's an interesting subject to me, and I'd like to try out a few of them. Call it a whim.

Comment: That doesn't mean you have to use a full product to test them out. Usually links to those are removed on purpose because they don't want people to accidentally get a hold of them. Only ones that you can possibly test are old kernel exploits in the linux kernel since the code is still around.

Comment: Have a quick pop over to [Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com), where you will find questions such as [this one](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/2330/485), on the relevance of buffer overflows, two questions listing [vulnerable servers](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/1735/485) and [operating systems](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/183/485) and useful folks to speak to regarding this sort of thing. Or you could migrate the question over there.

Answer (score 2):

There is a great book which teaches exploiting buffer overflows (amongst other vulnerabilities).  Book comes with a Linux LiveCD which is nicely set up with compilers/debuggers and plenty of exploitable programs.

Highly recommended if you haven't already picked it up:

[image]

[Hacking. The Art of Exploitation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593271441)

Answer (score 1):

> Can you name a program that's actually out there in the wild that has a known buffer overflow vulnerability?

Yes, but hopefully it will be patched before you are successfully able to demonstrate your attack. The longer a known vulnerability exists the more likely a the vulnerability will be patched (see queing theory). So, it is really the 'in the wild' part that is too restrictive. Why not try some historical vulnerabilities. [The Buffer Overfolw Page](https://engineering.purdue.edu/ResearchGroups/SmashGuard/BoF.html) at Perdue is a good place to start. They list RPC DCOM in ntdll.dll and Sendmail 8.11 has a [Remote Buffer Overflow](http://www.cert.org/advisories/CA-2003-07.html) bug. Additionally telnetd has a buffer overflow bug you can find in FreeBSD 4.3-RELEASE systems.

Answer (score 0):

The ability server is super to practice on. I wrote a research paper about this some years ago, which you can access here:

http://blog.sat0ri.com/reverse-code-engineering/2009/03/finding-exploiting-and-fixing-bugs-in-binaries/

This give a good introduction to vulnerabilities and uses the method vulnerability as an example.

I hope it is useful!

Regards,
sharpe

Comment: Link is broken now :\ Any backup?